# Is there a way to flash and make changes in micro sd card through pc which was flashed on raspberry pi

Tags: boot, 22.04

I installed ubuntu 22.04 on micro sd card and flashed it on raspberry pi zero.

I installed in headless mode. So I don't have monitor and other peripherals. I was able to connect with it through ssh. But now wifi password is changed, so I am not able to connect with it.

Is there a way to flash that micro sd card on my pc, to change wifi password?

Comment: Some RPis have an ethernet port. If yours has one, you can connect via an ethernet cable and modify the setting to match the new wifi password. Maybe you have the option is to reset the wifi password at least temporarily. And yes, if you know which file(s) to fix and how to do it, you can connect the SD card to a PC, mount the relevant partition with read/write permissions and do it.

Comment: @sudodus This sounds like a pretty good answer.

Comment: My understanding is that a drive, (SD card), created for ARM 64, (such as RPi's), does not work on AMD 64 motherboards and vice versa.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I think you are right, because I am not able to see any file that I had in raspberry pi when I mount sdcard on my mac.

Comment: There is probably an `ext4` root file system on the card. This file system should be possible to mount (and let you read files) by 'any Linux' operating system, for example Ubuntu, when running in some other computer. But Windows and MacOS are not good at reading ext4 and other Linux file systems, we could 'they do not want to read Linux file systems'.